# Greeting user upon opening bot

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am a beginner with Node.JS and the Microsoft Bot Framework. I am making a chatbot, and I have figured out how to communicate with the LUIS service, but I am still having trouble with one little problem. I have tried a lot of different things, and I should note that I am using the Online App Service Editor in Azure.

I cannot figure out how to greet the user, which I feel should be easy. By greeting, I mean send a message to the user upon them clicking the link to open dialog with my bot. I know that I should be using onMembersAdded command, but when I try to add it I always mess up something else. Here is my current code:

bot.js

```js
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');
const { LuisRecognizer } = require('botbuilder-ai');

class LuisBot {
    constructor(application, luisPredictionOptions) {
        this.luisRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer(application, luisPredictionOptions, true);
        }   
    async onTurn(turnContext) {
        // Make API call to LUIS with turnContext (containing user message)
        try {
            const results = await this.luisRecognizer.recognize(turnContext);

            //console.log(results);
            // Extract top intent from results
            const topIntent = results.luisResult.topScoringIntent;
            switch (topIntent.intent) {
                    case 'Greeting':
                    await turnContext.sendActivity('Hello!');
break;          
                    default:
                    await turnContext.sendActivity('Oops, looks like something went wrong');
            }
        } catch (error) {
        }
    }
}
module.exports.LuisBot = LuisBot;
```

index.js

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

// This bot's main dialog.
// const { EchoBot } = require('./bot');
const { LuisBot } = require('./bot');

// Import required bot configuration.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
dotenv.config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create HTTP server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nTo talk to your bot, open the emulator select "Open Bot"`);
});

// Create adapter.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    channelService: process.env.ChannelService,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata
});

const luisApplication = {
    applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
    endpointKey: process.env.LuisAuthoringKey,
    azureRegion: process.env.LuisAzureRegion
};
const luisPredictionOptions = {
    includeAllIntents: true,
    log: true,
    staging: false
};

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
};

// Create the main dialog.
// const bot = new EchoBot();
// Create the main dialog.
const bot = new LuisBot(luisApplication, luisPredictionOptions);

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // console.log(process.env.LuisAppId);
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        // console.log(process.env.LuisAppId);
        await bot.onTurn(context);
    });
});
```

I am obviously new to this and I apologize if this is a bad question, but I have tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

To implement only requires a little bit of code. Please be aware I am only showing the relevant code.

To start, have your greeting in a separate 'bot' file. In this example, I have a simple adaptive card defined in a file called `welcomeCard.json`. This is referenced in the greeting file, `welcomeBot.js`, which extends the main 'bot' file, `mainBot.js`.

**welcomeBot.js**

```
const { CardFactory } = require('botbuilder');
const { MainBot } = require('./mainBot');
const WelcomeCard = require('../resources/json/welcomeCard');

class WelcomeBot extends MainBot {
  constructor(conversationState, userState, dialog, conversationReferences) {
    super(conversationState, userState, dialog, conversationReferences);

    this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
      const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
      for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
        if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
          const welcomeCard = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(WelcomeCard);
          await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [welcomeCard] });
        }
      }

      await next();
    });
  }
}

module.exports.WelcomeBot = WelcomeBot;
```

Next, in the `index.js` file, I reference both the `welcomeBot` file and my `mainDialog` for instantiating the bot.

**index.js**

```js
const { WelcomeBot } = require( './bots/welcomeBot' );
const { MainDialog } = require( './dialogs/mainDialog' );

[...other code...]

const dialog = new MainDialog( 'MainDialog', userState, conversationState );
const bot = new WelcomeBot( conversationState, userState, dialog );
```

This *should* get you up and running with the greeting rendering when the user first connects to the bot.

Hope of help!